# Parallelising / scheduling python function call on many files

Tags: python, multiprocessing, dask

I have a few hundred thousand csv files I would all like to apply the same function to. Something like the following dummy function:

```py
def process_single_file(fname):
    df = pd.read_csv(fname)
    # Pandas and non-pandas processing
    df.to_csv(f"./output/{fname}")
```

As looping over all files individually would take too long, my question is what the most efficient way to schedule and parallelize this execution – no processes are dependent on each other. I started off trying to use python's `multiprocessing`:

```py
import multiprocessing

files = sorted(glob.glob("./input/*.csv"))

processes = []
for fname in files:
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_file, args=(fname,))
    processes.append(p)
    p.start()

for process in processes:
    process.join()
```

My computer, however, doesn't seem to like this process as it quickly overloads all CPU's and leading to slow-downs and crashes. Is there a more efficient way to reduce the workload of all CPU's and schedule the tasks such as using `Dask`, some `Bash` script or changing `python`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: use a `Pool` to limit the maximum processes.

Comment: In this case you can actually using `dask.delay` as in the last example of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63257331/4819376)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on where your bottleneck is : **are you spending more time reading / writing files, or doing CPU processing stuff ?**

This [RealPython tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/) really helped me a lot learning about all this stuff, I can only recommend a good read ;)

As explained in the tutorial, if I/O, multithreading is enough (and possibly better than multiprocessing):

```py
def process_all_files(files):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        executor.map(process_single_file, files)
```

And if CPU, multiprocessing will let you use all your available cores:

```py
def process_all_files(files):
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        pool.map(process_single_file, files)
```

Comment: File reading is very fast, the computation takes orders of magnitude longer. Thanks for the read

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Ray](https://docs.ray.io/en/master/), it is a quite efficient module to parallelize tasks

Comment: This is just an opinion. For stackoverflow, you should at least show *how* you would use ray, and what makes you think it would overcome the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely pool is the way to go.
Something along the below lines

`from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
return x*x

if **name** == '**main**':
pool = Pool(processes=4) `

check the following post

[Using multiprocessing.Process with a maximum number of simultaneous processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886565/using-multiprocessing-process-with-a-maximum-number-of-simultaneous-processes)